# Conversão de dados usando ComboBox

Tags: java, string, netbeans, conversão-de-tipo, combobox

Olá, Estou com dificuldade para tratar um erro no meu programa.

Tenho duas comboBox dentro de um painel de cadastro. Ao executa ja aparece a lista de produtos e clientes, porem o campo de código não esta preenchendo.
Criei um evento de PopupMenuWillBecomeInvisible em cada comboBox.

```java
private void preencherCodigoClientePeloCombobox(){        
       
        modelCliente  = controllerCliente.getClienteController(jcbNomeCliente.getSelectedItem().toString());
        jtfCodigoCliente.setText(String.valueOf(modelCliente.getIdCliente()));
    }
    
    
    
    private void preencherCodigoProdutoPeloCombobox(){
     
            modelProdutos = controllerProdutos.retornarProdutoController(jcbNomeProduto.getSelectedItem().toString());
            jtfCodigoProduto.setText(String.valueOf(modelProdutos.getIdProduto()));      

    }

E o java pedi para fazer a conversão de String para inteiro, Fiz asssim:

private void preencherCodigoClientePeloCombobox(){        
       
        modelCliente  = controllerCliente.getClienteController(Integer.parseInt(jcbNomeCliente.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        jtfCodigoCliente.setText(String.valueOf(modelCliente.getIdCliente()));
    }
    
    
    
    private void preencherCodigoProdutoPeloCombobox(){
     
            modelProdutos = controllerProdutos.retornarProdutoController(Integer.parseInt(jcbNomeProduto.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            jtfCodigoProduto.setText(String.valueOf(modelProdutos.getIdProduto()));      

    }
```

Só que continua com erro:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "teste"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at view.ViewVendas.preencherCodigoClientePeloCombobox(ViewVendas.java:538)
    at view.ViewVendas.<init>(ViewVendas.java:42)
    at view.ViewVendas$11.run(ViewVendas.java:531)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Alguma solução possivel?

Answer (score 0):

Você está com um `NumberFormatException`

Esta exceção está sendo lançada quando você faz a conversão de String pra o tipo inteiro `int`

Para evitar que esse problema ocorra você deve se certificar de que a String que você está convertendo pode ser transformada em int. Verifique se a sua String não possui espaços, caracteres especiais, letras qualquer coisa que não seja um número.

Note que você tentou converter a palavra "teste" pra `int`, isso nunca vai dar certo pois esta palavra não pode ser convertida em um número.
Você deveria passar uma string contendo números apenas.

```
String stringDeNumeros = "12345";
Int conversao = Integer.parseInt(string DeNumeros);
```

Isso funciona.

Mas o código abaixo não:

```
String stringDeNumeros = "teste12345";
Int conversao = Integer.parseInt(string DeNumeros);
```

Comment: tenho esses metodos que preencher minha comboBox com meus dados.